How do we know which sides are the width, height, thick, length...?
This is a heater in a standing position. How do we know which side is the width, height, thickness, length, etc.?
Is this picture correct?

Or is this one correct?

How do we know what to call each side?

There are usually three measurements: Height, Length, and Width but sometimes Depth is also included, thickness is the noun form of thick.

The answer is very easy to find. Here's a link to an image of a cardboard box with its measurements, note that it excludes the depth

Generally people seem to use either height or width in conjunction with length, in their eyes, length meaning the longest side of a 2D shape.

We use height of something that stands upright like your heater (i.e. the height is the longest dimension).

This is a worthwhile question with a good answer. I've tried to improve the phrasing in hopes of keeping it open.

Some objects require specific orientation to function properly. Others do not.
An object that must stand upright to function properly, like a heater, might be taller than it is wide (e.g height 28 inches, width 18 inches) when in use.  But when that object is placed in a box for shipment, it might be placed horizontally, in which case its depth (front-to-back when facing it during use) will become the height of the box (plus some inches for protective padding of some kind).
Height is always measured from the ground. Width is measured across the object. "Across" can be left-right/right-left as in a panorama, or it can be here-there/there-here, this-side-to-that-side, as with a lake. (However, we would not ask "What is the width of the lake?" but "How wide is the lake?") Depth is measured front-to-back on some things (e.g. a stove top, a fridge, a wall-mounted on-demand water heater) and top-to-bottom on other things (a swimming pool, a lake, a mine pit).  We could ask either "What is the depth of the lake?" or "How deep is the lake?"
Length is a linear measure independent of orientation. Except in shipping, when it usually refers to the longest edge.
